# JavaFX Confirm Windows dialog

Tags: javafx

please could you tell me, if there is some way how to confirm windows dialog from Java? For example dialog when you want to install printer - you have to confirm dialog before installing driver. I know thats not possible to do it with cmd. Only way is group policy...

So i am finding some way how to control windows built in dialogs.

Thank you...

Comment: That would be a high security risk and probably windows does everything it can to prevent you from doing this.

Comment: I want to confirm defined dialog - for printer for example. Something like Selenium Webdriver - confirm alert... Find some way to locate active windows dialog and confirm it from java app(tool for configuring, installing drivers...). So i dont want to confirm all windows dialogs everytime, but only some dialogs and only in my java app.

Answer (score 0):

In javafx, you can use Alert class for confirmation and other cases such as warning.

Here is the source:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html

The next alternative is building your own favorite dialog from scratch. It's a little bit of work, but you can customize what you want.